# How to store images in databases like mysql or oracle?

Tags: php, sql, database, image

I want to store images in a database. How this can be done using a Php page.

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: If you plan to store one image or two, then this is ok, but, if you plan to build a whole project that will store many images, then this is not a good practice, due to performance.

Comment: Store/upload the images in a path like `/assets/img/` and store the filename in your database.

Comment: you may store them in a blob cloumn

Comment: I am creating a  windows Desktop application using Visual Studio 2010 with c#,the app takes images from the user and stores it,and also retrieves images.If I use a database I have to configure a database in user's machine .What should i do?

Answer (score 4):

It's not a good idea to store images in DB because the database gets very huge with relatively a small amount of tupels. Store the path to your image on the filesystem in a column of your table instead. That keeps your databases size smaller. `database` is for `data` and a `filesystem` is for `files` (as their name already indicates).

If you still want to store images in database. Store images content (`file_get_contents($yourImageFile)`) in a column of type `BLOB`.

Comment: wouldn't a blob field fit better here?

Comment: why did you suggest base64 encoding? (I'm just asking)

Comment: Cause if you store it in a textfield that would be better but as BLOB field it doesn't make sense anymore.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer. Store only a link to the image file where you saved it in filesystem. So if you upload your image (e.x. `yourimage.jpg`) to `/var/www/your_app/images` store `/images/yourimage.jpg` in your DB and you can get the image again if you concatinate your app root dir and the path stored in the DB for your image.

Answer (score 1):

You can save image names to DB and you can use them in your application. Don't forget to put path before the image.

Comment: what will be the best way to store images,uploaded by user in a Windows Desktop Application,can the images can be stored and retrieved without any database such as MSSql,mysql etc.